# Offline Install of R on RedHat

Tags: r, redhat, epel

I am trying to install R on a RedHat server with no connectivity to the Internet. (sigh)

Initially, I tried with R meta package from EPEL (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Due to dependency requirements, I downloaded dependancies Rcore ,libRmath, etc...

**Each time it prompts for a dependency, I download, transfer and install.
This takes time and manual effort.**

Is there a cleaner way to do this than the *manual download, transfer and install* of every single dependency?

Note: The server has no internet connection, so yam is not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought of simply compiling R from source?
I usually do that, and it is relatively painless.

The  thing is that when you do the ./configure step 
you should get a list of all librarires that you 
need before you issue make.

It might be less of a hazzle than the redhat install 
you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I believed we are unable install R without online (unless there was someone download the installer and pass to you). You can refer to [Setup ®Studio Server](https://englianhu.github.io/Introducing-RStudio-Server-for-Data-Scientists.html) (CentOS/RHEL 7). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is install R on a server with internet access.
Install Rtools.

Then you install all the packages you need with the option `destdir` of install.packages.

You will then get a folder with all the packages you will need.